# A way for picking specific indices from an object where slicing isn't helpful

Tags: python, arrays, list, array-indexing

I'm looking for a way to access an object multiple times in an easy way.

Ex. 1)

```
ls = [i for i in range(100)]; print(ls[0], ls[32], ls[95])
```

Ex. 2)

```
js = {'key0': 'val0', ...}; print (js['keyN'], js['keyM'])
```

What I'm looking for is a way to only specify the object once, and then specify the wanted indices (something like slice). Meaning `ls[0,32,95]`, or `js['keyN][inner_keyN_M, innerkeyN_M+3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `itemgetter`module.

```
from operator import itemgetter
ls = [i for i in range(100)]
ids = [0, 32, 95]
print(itemgetter(*ids)(ls))
```

Output

```
(0, 32, 95)
```

You can also use list comprehension:

```
ls = [i for i in range(100)]
ids = [0, 32, 95]

print([ls[id] for id in ids])
```

Comment: I actually do something like this usually: `a,b,c = (obj[bla][key] for key in ('x','y','z'))`